# Passing generic function instance without explicitly enumerating template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <functional>

using FooFn = void(int, int, int);

template<class... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {
  // Do something
}

void bar(std::function<FooFn> fooFn) {
  fooFn(1, 2, 3);
}
```

I am able to pass `foo` with explicit template arguments:

```cpp
bar(&foo<int, int, int>);
```

I also can wrap `foo` in a generic lambda and pass it to a modified version of `bar`:

```cpp
template<class F>
void bar(F fooFn) {
  fooFn(1, 2, 3);
}
```

```cpp
bar([](auto... args){ foo(args...); });
```

But it decreases code readability.

Since the number of arguments to `FooFn` can be quite large, I want to avoid enumerating arguments (possibly using `FooFn` alias). How do I do that?

Comment: note: if it's defined as `using FooFn = void(int&&, int&&, int&&);` you can use it directly as parameter as `void bar(FooFn);`.

Comment: I know about the forwarding in lambda, it is here that way for simplicity. It definitely looks weird at the call site, it won't look any better at the declaration site either since `foo` is supposed to be a static member function. I just wonder if the language has any better way that I don't know of.

Comment: No, there isn't. But instead of writing out the lambda every time a macro that creates the lambda properly with perfect forwarding, `noexcept` forwarding, SFINAE-friendliness etc. is useful for this use case so that it becomes `bar(AS_LAMBDA(foo))` at the call site.